# Deletes are too slow in a merge table

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.0

I have a chat_log table which store data of sender and receiver. Structure is as

```
SENDER RECEIVER DATE
```

Current implementation: every month I create a MyIsam table say JAN to store all the chat done in January, FEB store all the chat done in February and so on.

say on MARCH 31 is have a merge table `chat_log` which contains multiple chat table JAN,FEB,MAR

On 1st april, I need to change the definition as FEB MARCH AND APRIL.

merge table work best here. Problem is when ever a user deletes its entry, i need to remove that entry from the table, since the table are merge myisam, this is happening very slowly.

so what should i do:

1. I may choose innodb and it would be faster but id don't support merge tables hence on every 1st changing definition would be difficult.
2. Using partitioning on merge wont be that much of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should use [partitions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning.html) rather than the MERGE storage engine.

The appropriate partitioning type seems to be [RANGE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-range.html).